# How to prevent recorded vba macro from swapping my cell values?

Tags: excel, vba

the context of this questions is with regards to the macro recording of the text to column function. My country uses dd/mm/yyyy date format, but a certain database in the company I'm working for uses mm/dd/yyyy. I am unable to change the date format of the database or the template prior to extracting because I am a lowly intern and the company is a MNC.

So my problem:

> [Manual Text to Column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YBWXk.png)
>   
> [Recorded macro Text to Column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kASFZ.png)
>   
> Column B is the raw data from the database, Columns AL to AN is where the the end result of the text is column is, so AL is Month, AM is Day and AN is Year. Column O is where I do =DATE(LEFT(AN,4),AL,AM) to get the dates in dd/mm/yyyy. 
>   
>   
> So dates in the format of mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm PM(12 hour format) are recognised as string, while dates in the mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm (24 hour format) are recognised as dates. The macro manages to split the string dates nicely with no issues, but for the date dates, as you can see from the 2 pictures linked, the values are swapped.

Hope someone can enlighten me regarding this quirky aspect of macro recording for Text to Column, I apologise if my explanation of my problem is not sufficient/detailed enough, let me know if you need more information! Thanks in advance.

Edit:
I only realised I forgot to include the recorded vba code after I turned off my computer, my bad.

```
Sub TextToCol()
'
' TextToCol Macro
'

'
Columns("B:B").Select
Range("B3").Activate
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("AL1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
    Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=True, OtherChar _
    :="/", FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1)), _
    TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
End Sub
```

Comment: Without seeing the code you are using, I doubt if you will receive much help.  (BTW - the dates that are being treated as string, rather than as dates, are the ones that have an invalid "month" component - so "09/27", i.e. 27 September, is left as text, but "11/3", i.e. 3 November, is treated as a date of 11 March.)  When you recorded the macro, did you specify that the "date" column should be treated as text, or as a date, or as "general" format?

Comment: @YowE3K Are you referring to the third step of the text to column(1) or the cell format for the entire column(2)? (1) I have tried choosing general, text and date in DMY and date in MDY, the values still get swapped  (2) I left it as it is, if i change it to text or general, the date dates become a number like 42440.47. I have just changed it to short date and did the text the column, the values still get swapped when I run the macro.

Comment: Sorry - I was thinking that your text to column code was happening while importing the data into Excel.  From your last comment I assume that you have already loaded the data into Excel (some as dates and some as text) before even attempting the text to column step.  That is going to make things hard, but you could add an extra column which converts dates back to text (e.g. `=IF(ISNUMBER(B4),TEXT(B4,"mm/dd/yyyy"),B4)`) and then use text to columns on that new column.  But it would be a lot easier to just import the data into Excel as text to begin with.

Comment: @YowE3K Thanks for the help! After making everything into text the macro finally works without any swapping. However, I have to make another column to paste as 'Values only' as the text to column sees the  column as formulas like so http://imgur.com/a/puYtH but this is just something minor. So just for my own understanding, do you have any idea why the macro for text to column swaps the values?

Comment: I don't know **why** it does it, but it appears that the VBA version of the text to columns is locale-independent, and therefore always treats dates as if they are in "mm/dd/yyyy" format.  The UI version seems to take locale into account, and therefore uses "dd/mm/yyyy" format, thus splitting cell B7's value of `1 October 2017` (which was originally 10 January 2017 in your database) into `1`, `10` and `2017`.  Both versions treat text fields as text fields.  (If I was you, I would still be taking a step back and working out how to get the data into Excel as text to begin with.)